# Newton Method using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have written the following code for Newton algorithm to minimize the error by using two different starting points. They should not be on the principle axis of the ellipses of error function contours.

```
R=[0.5 -0.25;-0.25 0.5];
P=[0;-0.866];
Pt=transpose(P);
Rinv=[2.67 1.33;1.33 2.67];
M=6;  %number of iterations
mu=1/2;  %step size
for k=1:M
    W(1)=1.16; %initial weight value
    W(2)=2.32;
    G(k)=2*R*W(k)-2*P;
end
for k=2:M
    W(1)=1.16;
    W(2)=2.32;
    W(k+1)=W(k)-mu*Rinv*G(k);
end
for k=1:M
    Wtrans(k)=trans(W(k));
    E(k)=Wtrans(k)*R*W(k)-2*Pt*W(k)+2;   % error function.
end
plot(E(k));
```

Can someone please let me what is wrong in this code? I am unable to plot it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reach the last line of your code, k is not 1:M like you think, but simply the scalar value M.  Do plot(E) instead of plot(E(k))

Comment: I tried.. I am still not able to plot it !!

Comment: I ran your code.  You didn't mention you had an error before you tried to plot.  Line 10 (G(k)=2*R*W(k)-2*P;) fails: R*W(k) is a 2x2 matrix to which you try to subtract a 2x1 vector.  The dimensions do not agree.  There are many more errors in your code as well (such as not defining W(k) for k>2 even though you use that value).  You will have to resolve your errors one at a time, making sense of the error messages from MATLAB, and using whos to print the dimensions of all variables you manipulate to understand your errors.  But when you reach the end, you will want plot(E), not plot(E(k)).

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer and if you are unable to resolve one of these errors I mention, you open up another question about that specific error, including the error message you get from MATLAB, and why the error message does not make sense to you.